# Error 404 al consumir servicio REST de Genexus desde Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rest, genexus

Tengo una aplicación Java hecha en Genexus 15 U1 (java-mysql-tomcat8), donde he creado un procedimiento con propiedad REST protocol en true, cuyos parámetros en rule son (la salida es un sdt): 
parm(in:&DtCatCSec,in:&TdaCod,in:&pagina,in:&TdaCatCod,out:&SDTC_CatProductos);

He tratado de llamar a este servicio desde javascript de la siguiente manera:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://192.168.2.113:8090/Gx15RingoStoreJavaMySQL/rest/PrC_WSProductos",
  data: JSON.stringify({
  DtCatCSec: 1,
  TDAcOD: "0000000472",
  pagina: 1,
  TdaCatCod: "0000000607"
}),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "contentType": "charset=UTF-8"
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
    //Do stuff with the JSON data
    alert("ok");
    /*
   $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
      var texto = "<div><p>"+item.SmoothResMenuData[i].Title+"</p></div>"
      $(texto).appendTo( "#images" );
    });
    */
  },
  error: function ( jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){
    var err = "ERROR:"+jqXHR+"-"+textStatus+"-"+errorThrown;
    alert(err);
  }
```

Pero me devuelve el error en consola del navegador: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Mi configuracion en el web.xml del tomcat es la siguiente:

```html
 <filter>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://192.168.2.113:8090</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-OriginContent-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Content-Type,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>2592000</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
    <extension>html</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html;charset=UTF-8;application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Es la primera vez que hago este tipo de integraciones, agradezco de antemano su ayuda!!!

Comment: los errores 404 no se dan por errores de implementación sino por errores de ubicación. 404 quiere decir que el servicio no está donde los estás buscando

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné yo misma mi error jeje, esta es la manera correcta de llamar un servicio rest de Genexus desde JS, deben haber más, pero esta me funcionó:

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://192.168.2.113:8080/Gx15RingoStoreJavaMySQL/rest/PrC_WSProductos",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\"DtCatCSec\" : 1,\n\"TDAcOD\" : \"0000000472\",\n\"pagina\" : 1,\n\"TdaCatCod\" : \"0000000607\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El Error 404 indica que esta URL

http://192.168.2.113:8090/Gx15RingoStoreJavaMySQL/rest/PrC_WSProductos

a la que le haces el request no es alcanzable; esta documentado aquí:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

en cuanto al código la manera correcta de llamar a un servicio rest desde genexus es:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://192.168.2.113:8080/Gx15RingoStoreJavaMySQL/rest/PrC_WSProductos",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\"DtCatCSec\" : 1,\n\"TDAcOD\" : \"0000000472\",\n\"pagina\" : 1,\n\"TdaCatCod\" : \"0000000607\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**o con javascript vanilla: no verificado**

```
xhttp.open("POST", "http://192.168.2.113:8080/Gx15RingoStoreJavaMySQL/rest/PrC_WSProductos", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhttp.send("{\n\"DtCatCSec\" : 1,\n\"TDAcOD\" : \"0000000472\",\n\"pagina\" : 1,\n\"TdaCatCod\" : \"0000000607\"\n}");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch